# How to write to second tree in Realtime Database – Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, crud

I have a Firebase Realtime Database and I want to write to it, that's simple enough, but I have added more than one tree to my Database and want to know how to write to the second tree. Right now I can only write to the first tree.
Image for better understanding:
[image: Firebase Realtime Database]

So for example how can I write to the Color info.

**Note**: The first line of string (User line in image) is the users id token (currentFirebaseUser.uid)
//uid = User ID
and the second line of string(Info line in image) is automatically generated by firebase

Database code:

```
  _getDBRides() {
    return Expanded(
      child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: dbRef,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {
          Map Rides = snapshot.value as Map;
          //unique key/id of each item in db
          Rides['key'] = snapshot.key;
          return listItem(Rides: Rides);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
// If there is one tree in the database then I can reference it like this

Rides['Color']

// But because there is another tree I don't know how to write to it
```

What I have tried:
`Rides['key']['Color']` doensn't work

Seems short but I have tried writing it in different ways too to see how to write to that tree but nothing work and the documentation doesn't seem to show how to write to a second tree.